# Blend 2015 - couple questions

Tags: wpf, vb.net, blend

Have some questions regarding Visual Studio Blend tool below:

> 1. Can i use Blend to prepare windows for Windows Forms applications or it's only for wpf applications?
> 2. If yes on 1st point how to do it (how to import such forms)?
> 3. If i am working with wpf applications can i just prepare my user interface and also develop code within Blend instead of doing windows
>      in Blend and then switch to normal Visual studio to develop code?

Comment: Blend is better for designing, VS is better for coding, but you can do both in each

Comment: does blend contains more tools for design that i can do in vs?

Comment: Yes: See http://wildermuth.com/2009/6/10/Blend_and_Visual_Studio_-_Why_Two_Tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, it's a XAML deisgner, for WPF and UWP etc.
2. N/A
3. Yes. It's a code editor, and will compile and run your project, and you can switch between VS and Blend. The switching experience is further improved in Visual Studio 2015, I personally hop between the 2 regularly.

Comment: but why to switch from Blend to normall VS if in Blend i can developep code and making graphic?

Comment: Much more code focused tools, debugging, refactoring etc.